# Maven and regular Java can be used in single eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, netbeans, jar

In Eclipse IDE, it is displaying as a Maven project and Java project. How different are they from each other. Can we make use of regular jars and maven jars in a single project? Else, have to use maven and regular java jars separately?

Comment: Make a decision and use only one. Use Maven and maintain your dependencies in your pom file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `maven` project is a java (or scala) project which uses `apache maven` as dependency management and build tool. Normally, you don't need to add "regular" jars as almost every dependency is on the maven central (https://search.maven.org/) which you just add to your `pom.xml`, the actual jar is then automatically downloaded from the remote repository.

If you have a jar which is not on the maven central (i.e. e third-party jar or a jar from an own project), you can install this jar in your local (or enterprise) maven repository, see e.g. https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com is **NOT** maven central. This is central: https://search.maven.org

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks, I corrected my answer. I always thought http://mvnrepository.com/ is a frontend to the same repository...

Comment: It's a third party site that provides a cleaner searching feature, IMO, notice it's not "maven.org", though.

Comment: I have a different opinion about the "cleaner searching"...cause https://search.maven.org works perfect....and has REST API etc.